# Piping via FFMPEG make loose file duration

Tags: ffmpeg, piping

In order to dynamically encode file and upload them to a server, I output `ffmpeg` to pipe:1 and use curl to post the result to a file.

The problem is when I use `MediaInfo` to check the file, it appears as 'Open / Incomplete' and the duration is no longer available. Is there a solution to make the piping properly closing the file ?

I have also pipe locally the output to check if it is related to the upload, but the problem is still there.

Here is my command :

`ffmpeg -i myFile.mxf -vcodec copy -filter_complex "[0:1:a]channelsplit[left1][right1];[left1]asplit=1[a1];[right1]asplit=1[a2]" -map 0:v:0 -map "[a1]" -map "[a2]"  -c:a:0 pcm_s24le -b:a:0 1152k -ar:0 48k -c:a:1 pcm_s24le -b:a:1 1152k -ar:1 48000 -f mxf pipe:1 > myFile_ff_pipe_local.mxf`

Thanks in advance \m/

Comment: With many muxers, if the output isn't seekable, trailers and sometimes headers won't be identical to what they would be if writing to a file. MXF is one of them.

Comment: OK thanks, so there is no way to make the output seekable via piping. I have tried with using `-t duration` but the result is the same